# How to send a SIGHUP signal to PostgREST on Heroku from another Node.js program?

Tags: node.js, caching, heroku, signals, postgrest

I have a [PostgREST](https://postgrest.com) instance deployed on Heroku using [the buildpack](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest-heroku).

The Postgres schemas are created by a Node.js program that uses [node-pg-migrate](https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate).

After the migrations have run, the schema is changed and PostgREST needs to [reload the schema](https://postgrest.com/en/v4.4/admin.html#schema-reloading) to update its schema cache.

To refresh the cache without restarting the PostgREST server there's the option to send the server process a SIGHUP signal: `killall -HUP postgrest`

Since I have the migrations running from a Node.js program (`npm run migrate:up`) it seems to make sense to send that signal with a post-migration script. I'm not even sure if I can send such a signal from another server to the PostgREST instance.

Basically, what I'm asking is how to send a SIGHUP signal to PostgREST on Heroku from a Node.js program on another server.

Answer (score 2):

One way to trigger the schema reload across servers is to have your post-migration script run `NOTIFY postgrest_reload;` in the database to which PostgREST is attached. Then on the same server as PostgREST, run a tool like [pg_listen](https://github.com/begriffs/pg_listen) to catch that event and send the sighup. For instance: `pg_listen <db-uri> postgrest_reload "killall -HUP postgrest"`.

You can even make PostgREST automatically reload its schema cache whenever the schema changes (using a DDL trigger), as explained in https://postgrest.com/en/v4.4/admin.html#schema-reloading

Comment: However on Heroku it would require modifying the buildpack to include pg_listen. We've been looking into adding LISTEN support right inside the postgrest binary, but it requires a feature in our postgresql access library that is not yet available.